# Trying to name Delegate method per conventions, Xcode "expecting a type"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have a class `GameController`.

I have a delegate method to update the player's score.

Per [naming conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html):

> Start the name by identifying the class of the object that’s sending the message:

I'm trying to name the method:

`-(void) GameController: (GameController *) game didUpdatePlayerScore:(NSInteger)score;`

But Xcode is telling me that it's expecting a type for the `(GameController *)`.

The protocol is defined in the `GameController.h` file and AutoComplete offers GameController as a suggestion when typing so I'm not sure how to proceed other than not follow conventions.

Comment: Did you do `@class GameController;` before declaring your protocol? And you should start the method name with a lowercase (`gameController: didUpdatePlayerScore:`).

Comment: @Larme  I don't.  I assume that should be done after `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`?  That did the trick.  If you make it an answer I will accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote this:

```
#import "WhateverNeeded"

@protocol CustomDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)gameController:(GameController *)game didUpdatePlayerScore:(NSInteger)score;
@end

@interface GameController : NSObject
@end
```

The issue is that you don't know yet `GameController`. It's a unknown class.
That's why you have to put `@class GameController;` just before the `@protocol` declaration. It's *Forward Declaration* (you can look for it since it's used for various things) In other words, it say: "Don't worry, `GameController` exists, it's declared somewhere after".

Bonus: Start your methods with a lower case (`gameController:ZzZ` vs `GameController:ZzZ`).